# Chi-square calculation for non-linear model goodness of fit

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting, chi-squared

I would like to be certain that the way i calculate $\chi^2$ is correct as I get really low values (when comparing to the critical $\chi^2$). I wanted at first to use the reduced chi square statistics but found out : https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3754, that it cannot be done here since I have a non-linear model).

You can see on the code below that I am trying to develop a method so that I can know whether my data is looking like a straight-horizontal line or a gaussian. The problem I have is how could I compare the 2 values that scipy returns for chi ? In the example below my data is looking like a gaussian but the print(chi_gaussian, chi_line) returns: 0.04014802138783562 0.003509148221940015, so a smaller value for the line-fit, maybe I should compare those to a critical value but I'm not sure how I can do that since the degrees of freedom are difficult to estimate ?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import chisquare

def gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma):
    return H + A * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

def horiz(x,c):
    return np.full_like(x, c)

# generate some data containing a Gaussian bump
n = 10_000  # number of data points
x = np.linspace(0, 1_000_000, n, dtype=float)

# random Gaussian noise
y = np.random.randn(n) * 5e-8

# Gaussian bump parameters
sigma = 30_000
x0 = 400_000
H = 0
A = 4.5e-7

y += gauss(x, H, A, x0, sigma)

# scale factors
scaleamp = 1e8
scalerange = 1e-5

# initial parameter guesses
iniguess = (0.1e-7 * scaleamp, 1e-7 * scaleamp, 350000.0 * scalerange, 10000.0 * scalerange)

# fit Gaussian bump model
gaussfit = curve_fit(gauss, x * scalerange, y * scaleamp, p0=iniguess)

# fit horizontal line model
linefit = curve_fit(horiz, x, y * scaleamp, p0=(0.0,))

Hf, Af, x0f, sigmaf = gaussfit[0]

# rescale best fit parameters to generate the Gaussian model
bestgaussfit = gauss(x, Hf / scaleamp, Af / scaleamp, x0f / scalerange, sigmaf / scalerange)

# generate the best fit horizontal line model
bestlinefit = horiz(x, linefit[0][0] / scaleamp)

#### Chi square calculation
chi_g, p_g = chisquare(y, bestgaussfit)
chi_l, p_l = chisquare(y, bestlinefit)
print(chi_g, chi_l)

### Plot data and fits
plt.plot(x, y, label ='data')
plt.plot(x, bestlinefit, label = 'linefit')
plt.plot(x, bestgaussfit, label = 'gauss fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: output of code]